# Error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' al migrar Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Me encuentro con un error al realizar la migración en Laravel 5.5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi archivo de migración:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfessionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profesiones', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profesiones');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje es claro, la tabla de usuarios *(users)* ya existe actualmente en su base de datos. Tiene varias opciones, mencionaré dos

1. Eliminar la tabla `users` de la base de datos manualmente y ejecutar `php artisan migrate`
2. Ejecutar simplemente el comando `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Si tiene `seeders` recuerde añadir al final `--seed` para las dos opciones.